# @font-face weight appearing differently on two pages in safari

Tags: css, font-face

In Safari, my @font-face typeface appears to have more weight, or at least crisper on [this page](http://dev.lecollective.co.uk/clients/2016/polly_king/calendar/).
Compared to [this page](http://dev.lecollective.co.uk/clients/2016/polly_king/).

Both pages use the same styles so I cannot figure out what would be causing this

[image]

Comment: Text looks to be rendered the same on both pages for me. (Viewed in Chrome, Firefox and Edge..)

Comment: Yeah, looks fine in Chrome and Firefox. But as mentioned above, the issue is in Safari